# PrestaShop 1.6 Back Office pagination not working correctly

Tags: php, prestashop, payment, prestashop-1.6

Hello I'm developing PrestaShop paymnet module. I wish list all transaction and made that with Helper List class, I set paggination option, but paggination don't work correctly. At the bottom shows paggionation like 1..2..4 pages, but list all transaction. This is part of code from render helper list method.

```
$helper = new HelperList();

$helper->show_toolbar = false;
$helper->no_link = true; 
$helper->_pagination = array(10, 20, 50, 100, 200);

$content = $this->getCancelRows();
$helper->listTotal = count($this->getCancelRows());

return $helper->generateList($content, $this->fields_list);
```

Thank for all helping! I'sorry if I ask dublicate question, but my research end with unsuccess. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. Just must be added functionality for paginate the result. If somebody has similar problem. Below I paste working code.

```
public function initList() {

    $content = $this->getCancelRows();
    $helper->listTotal = count( $this->getCancelRows() );

    /* Paginate the result */
    $page = ( $page = Tools::getValue( 'submitFilter' . $helper->table ) ) ? $page : 1;
    $pagination = ( $pagination = Tools::getValue( $helper->table . '_pagination' ) ) ? $pagination : 10;
    $content = $this->paginate_content( $content, $page, $pagination );

    return $helper->generateList( $content, $this->fields_list );

}

public function paginate_content( $content, $page = 1, $pagination = 10 ) {

   if( count($content) > $pagination ) {
        $content = array_slice( $content, $pagination * ($page - 1), $pagination );
   }

   return $content;

}
```